# Unwanted blank page before title in Latex

Tags: latex

there is an Unwanted blank page before title in Latex, and I don't understand why there are string *"_result_result"* in this blank page, I am pretty sure I didn't add them
Here is my code.
**I am editing in overleaf and using *LuaLaTex* **

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twocolumn,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,chains}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\geometry{centering,textwidth=0.887589cm,columnsep=.81cm,left=1.6cm,right=1.6cm,top=1.91cm,bottom=2.54cm}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[]{caption2} 
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.} 
\renewcommand{\captionlabeldelim}{.~} 
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{Figure.\arabic{figure}(\alph{subfigure})}
\makeatletter \renewcommand{\@thesubfigure}{\thesubfigure\space}
\renewcommand{\p@subfigure}{} \makeatother
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\centering\textbf}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\indent\small\centering\textbf}{\hspace{1cm}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}.}
\newcommand{\upcite}[1]{\textsuperscript{\textsuperscript{\cite{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\tnewroman}{\fontspec{Times New Roman}}
\providecommand{\keywords}[1]
{
  \footnotesize     
  \textbf{Key words --} #1
}
\providecommand{\abstrct}[1]
{
 \footnotesize  
  \textbf{Abstract --} #1
} 
\newcommand{\tabincell}[2]{\begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}} 

\setlength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip}
%set font style
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
%set title and author
\title{\vspace{-1cm}My title}

%begin the document
\begin{document}
\maketitle
```

[the unwanted blank page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAe29.png)

Answer (score 2):

Please don't ignore the errors and warnings in the .log file. they exactly tell you which of your package are incompatible and which commands are missing.

To summarise the changes:

- lots of incompatible packages
- syntax errors in `\titleformat`. In particular you must not write `\titleformat{}{}`
- writing `\textbf some text` is wrong. It is a macro so you either need `\textbf{some text}` or `\bfseries some text`
- you should clean up your preamble, many of the packages are redundant, make no sense or are loaded multiple times.

---

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex


\documentclass[letterpaper,twocolumn,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,chains}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\geometry{centering,textwidth=0.887589cm,columnsep=.81cm,left=1.6cm,right=1.6cm,top=1.91cm,bottom=2.54cm}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage[]{caption2} 
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.} 
%\renewcommand{\captionlabeldelim}{.~} 
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{Figure.\arabic{figure}(\alph{subfigure})}
\makeatletter \renewcommand{\@thesubfigure}{\thesubfigure\space}
\renewcommand{\p@subfigure}{} \makeatother
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\centering\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\indent\small\centering\bfseries\hspace{1cm}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}.}
\newcommand{\upcite}[1]{\textsuperscript{\textsuperscript{\cite{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\tnewroman}{\fontspec{Times New Roman}}
\providecommand{\keywords}[1]
{
  \footnotesize     
  \textbf{Key words --} #1
}
\providecommand{\abstrct}[1]
{
 \footnotesize  
  \textbf{Abstract --} #1
} 
\newcommand{\tabincell}[2]{\begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}} 

\setlength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip}
%set font style
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
%set title and author
\title{\vspace{-1cm}My title}
\author{names}

%begin the document
\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\justifying

%%











\begin{thebibliography}{00}
\bibitem{1}My bib
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks!your code worked well, but my problem is that there is still a blank page before my title page like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAe29.png

Comment: @chenL2.71 Please make a [mre] that reproduces the problem. The code from my answer works fine on overleaf https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzIJF.png

Comment: yeah, I found it's because of my use of the Reference. When I add References like this https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QTCfjcwgdS/  ,things went wrong. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: @chenL2.71 You could start to fix this by removing all the incompatible packages I commented out in my answer and also fix the syntax errors in `\titleformat` I corrected in my answer. I just fixed one more syntax error which caused the problem with the bibliography

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't pay attention to the errors before because I thought it compiled well. My blank page problem has bee solved, I found it's because of my wrong setting of one table's caption. Thank you again, have a nice weekend!

Comment: @chenL2.71 Overleaf is exceptional good at hiding error messages, you'll have to be very careful to not miss them